# PHP fails to update after forced refreshing

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wamp, wampserver

I am developing a Wordpress theme and noticed that updates do not happen very fast at all. Sometimes a force refresh, CTRL F5 does it, other times I just have to wait several minutes. On the latest round I seem to not be seeing any changes even after waiting a while.

Things I've troubleshooted:

1. Force refreshing as noted above
2. Disabled OPcache in phpi.ini of the folder/version listed in PHPinfo() (already set to 0).
3. number 2 except for the php.ini in the Apache folder (already set to 0)
4. Added `php_flag opcache.enable Off` to the .htaccess file of the local directory housing Wordpress. inside the IFModule tag

This is a fresh wordpress install with no plugins including caching ones. I am using chrome for testing.

Any other ideas for how to solve this?

EDIT: phpinfo() reports the following about opcache:

```
opcache.blacklist_filename  no value    no value
opcache.consistency_checks  0   0
opcache.dups_fix    Off Off
opcache.enable  Off Off
opcache.enable_cli  Off Off
opcache.enable_file_override    Off Off
opcache.error_log   no value    no value
opcache.fast_shutdown   0   0
opcache.file_update_protection  2   2
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180 180
opcache.inherited_hack  On  On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 4   4
opcache.load_comments   1   1
opcache.log_verbosity_level 1   1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   2000    2000
opcache.max_file_size   0   0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   5   5
opcache.memory_consumption  64  64
opcache.mmap_base   no value    no value
opcache.optimization_level  0x7FFFBFFF  0x7FFFBFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model  no value    no value
opcache.protect_memory  0   0
opcache.restrict_api    no value    no value
opcache.revalidate_freq 2   2
opcache.revalidate_path Off Off
opcache.save_comments   1   1
opcache.use_cwd On  On
opcache.validate_permission Off Off
opcache.validate_timestamps On  On
```

Comment: On chrome you can do a hard refresh `ctr`-`shift`-`r`

Comment: Have you added your site url's in the wp-config.php file??

Comment: No I have not, I will read up on that now.